# Firestore Nested Array

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a Vue action to update an array of 'Tags' saved on a document in Firestore using ArrayUnion but I'm getting the following error ...

> Error: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom e object (found in field tags)

I'm using VUE and Vuetfiy with Vuex with the following dependencies ...

```
 "dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "firebase": "^5.7.0",
    "vee-validate": "^2.1.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
    "vuetify": "^1.3.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

and importing firebase as below .....

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const config = {
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
  databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)

const firestore = firebase.firestore()
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true}
firestore.settings(settings)

export const db = firebase.firestore()
```

My action is ....

```
renameCompanyTagsInUse ({commit, getters}) {
    db.collection('programs').doc(getters.programId).collection('companies').doc('FzPNtNx8ndMh5P4tHhr9').update({
      tags: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('TestTag')})
    .catch(
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
    commit('setTagsChanged', {oldTag: '', newTag: ''})
    commit('setLoadingButton', false)
    commit('setSnackbar', {status: true, text: 'Company tag updated'})
    setTimeout(() => { commit('setSnackbar', [false, '...']) }, 3000)
  },
```

The new tag 'TestTag' should be added to the array 'tags' nested in the companies doc ID FzPNtNx8ndMh5P4tHhr9

Comment: try this `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('TestTag') ) )`

Comment: Thanks OK, it did update the firestore DB but had removed all other elements in the array and nested 2 new arrays called _elements and _methodName under the tags array, which is not what I expected or am requiring

Comment: if you want to update one specific field in `tags` object, IMO you need to specify it. ex: { tags.values: ['word', 'cloud']}

Comment: Thank OK, but unfortunately Firestore doesn't support updates, just add and delete of items in a nested array such that I am using to track tags